# Cómo resolver el error: "Use of uninitialized value $campanasTotal in concatenation (.) or string at ..."

Tags: perl

**Error:** *Daemon Perl Use of uninitialized value $campanasTotal in concatenation (.) or string at     /var/lib/tool/devueltosmh.pl line 374*

**Resultado `use diagnostics;`**

```
*Use of uninitialized value $campanasTotal in concatenation (.) or string at
/var/lib/tool/devueltosmh.pl line 374 (#1)
(W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already
defined.  It was interpreted as a "" or a 0, but maybe it was a mistake.
To suppress this warning assign a defined value to your variables.

To help you figure out what was undefined, perl will try to tell you the
name of the variable (if any) that was undefined. In some cases it cannot
do this, so it also tells you what operation you used the undefined value
in.  Note, however, that perl optimizes your program and the operation
displayed in the warning may not necessarily appear literally in your
program.  For example, "that $foo" is usually optimized into "that "
. $foo, and the warning will refer to the concatenation (.) operator,
even though there is no . in your program.*
```

Código:

```
$emailBody  = "El proceso finalizo con exito\n\n";
$emailBody .= "================================\n";
$emailBody .= "Total devueltos procesados: ".$devueltosTotal."\n";
$emailBody .= "\n";
$emailBody .= "Total campanas procesados: ".$campanasTotal."\n";
$emailBody .= "================================\n";
$emailBody .= "Hora Inicio: ".$startDate."\n";
$emailBody .= "Hora Final: ".$endDate."\n";
$emailBody .= "================================\n\n";
$emailBody .= "Administrador\n";
$emailMensaje = encode('utf8', decode('iso-8859-1', $emailBody));
```

**Donde :** `$emailBody .= "Total campanas procesados: ".$campanasTotal."\n";` Sería la linea afectada

Comment: $campanasTotal no tiene valor como bien indica el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use of uninitialized value `<variable>`

La advertencia se debe a que no le asignaste ningún valor a esa variable, y estás intentando obtener dicho valor.

Posibles escenarios:

- Muchas veces sucede por un error tipográfico al usar la variable. Por ejemplo, era `$totalCampanas` y se usó `$campanasTotal` en alguna línea.
- O cuando se declara, pero no se le asigna un valor:

  ```
  my $campanasTotal;  # <-- se declaró

  say $campanasTotal; # <-- pero aún no tiene ningún valor. ¡¿Intentamos mostrarlo?!
  ```
- Otras veces, se debe a que se definen dentro de alguna estructura de control, pero que no termina ejecutando. Por ejemlo, este código daría el mismo error:

  ```
  if (123 == 654) { # <-- siempre falso. La variable nunca se declara
      my $campanasTotal = 3;
  }
  print "Total campanas procesadas: ".$campanasTotal; # <-- ERROR!!!

  # //> Use of uninitialized value $campanasTotal in concatenation (.) or string
  ```
- Como resultado de una asignación, una variable podría quedar como `undef`. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  my ($coincidencia) = $texto =~ /($regex)/i;  # <-- cuando no coincide, queda undef

  print "Coincidencia: ".$coincidencia;
  ```

---

Es importante aclarar que no es un error, sino una advertencia. El script se va a seguir ejecutando.

Suele ser recomendable agregar al inicio de tu script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

para poder identificar errores antes de que se generen al ejecutar.

Comment: Aclarar que cuando Mariano dice "Nothing" se refiere al valor 'undef' (indefinido) de Perl.

Comment: Gracias @Joaquín. Creo que me mezclé lenguajes. Hace años que no toco Perl. Corregido